# Json takes multiple attempts to get downloaded correctly

Tags: android, json, android-volley, okhttp

I am asking the same question I asked previously as I'm unable to solve the issue. You can follow the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017707/unable-to-get-correct-json

Don't be judgemental before trying it manually at your end.I'd like to know where am I mistaking here.

Thanks

Older Post:-
I've 1 url: http://alolma.coderswebsites.com/api/v1/person/ and I tried following diff libs but unable to parse the correct json.

It shows org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 21001 while using okhttp.
� while using volley (with parseNetworkResponse also).
com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9- it aprses the json but here, new issues arises that the size of the result array varies (I don't know how) & I use the count jsonobj to match the size of it but it takes 5-8 hits to get the correct json data.
Plz help me and let me know wh this happening, the data is in UT-8 already,so I did not decode it.

Volley coding:-
     public void getPersonList(Context context) {

```
UTF8StringRequest  stringRequest = new UTF8StringRequest (com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET,"http://alolma.coderswebsites.com/api/v1/person/",
        new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("response",response);

               try{
                   list.clear();

                   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);


                   count=obj.getInt("count");
                   Log.d("count",""+count);


                   Log.d("lenofresult",""+obj.getJSONArray("results").length());
                   for (int i=0; i<obj.getJSONArray("results").length(); i++) {
                       Person person = new Person();
                       person.parse(obj.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(i));

                       list.add(person);
                   }

                   Log.d("list.siz()",""+list.size());

                   if (list.size()==count)
                   { Log.d("data","100%");
                       loadagain=false;
                       list2=list;
                       callBack.onSuccess();
                   }

               }
               catch (Exception e){}

            }
        },
        new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


            }
        }){




};
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
int socketTimeout = 30000;//30 seconds - change to what you want
RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

}

For this I use -
 public class UTF8StringRequest extends StringRequest {
    public UTF8StringRequest(int method, String url, com.android.volley.Response.Listener listener, com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, listener, errorListener);
    }

```
public UTF8StringRequest(String url, com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String> listener, com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(url, listener, errorListener);
}

@Override
protected com.android.volley.Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

    String utf8String = null;
    try {
        utf8String = new String(response.data, "UTF-8");
        return com.android.volley.Response.success(utf8String, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return com.android.volley.Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

}

try asynctask-
  class getdata extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    loadagain=false;

    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Log.d("inside","getunseenmsg");
    String s="";

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://alolma.coderswebsites.com/api/v1/person/");

        final  InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();

        final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader
                = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");

        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        char[] buffer = new char[2000];
        while (inputStreamReader.read(buffer, 0, 2000) != -1) {
            stringBuffer.append(buffer);
        }


        Log.d("RAW_STRING", stringBuffer.toString());
        list.clear();


        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(stringBuffer.toString());
        inputStreamReader.close();

        count=obj.getInt("count");
        Log.d("count",""+count);


        Log.d("lenofresult",""+obj.getJSONArray("results").length());
        for (int i=0; i<obj.getJSONArray("results").length(); i++) {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.parse(obj.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(i));

            list.add(person);
        }

        Log.d("list.siz()",""+list.size());

        if (list.size()==count)
        { Log.d("data","100%");
            loadagain=false;
            list2=list;
            callBack.onSuccess();
        }
        else
        { loadagain=true;
            getPersonList();}




    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        Log.d("list.siz()",""+list.size());
        list.clear();

        if (list.size()==count & count>0)
        {Log.d("data","100%");
            loadagain=false;
            list2.addAll(list);
            callBack.onSuccess();

        }
        else
        { loadagain=true;
            getPersonList();}


    }



    return s;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

protected void onPostExecute(String params) {
    super.onPostExecute(params);



}
```

}

Comment: Your linked question is unavailable.

Comment: sorry, that link got dead, Updated the codes here

Comment: I've used volley before and I really prefer OKHttp over it, it caused unexpected issues and errors and I never had those issues again after moving to OKHttp with Retrofit

Comment: I've tried volley,okhttp and normal calls, but got the same result, as I mentioned here. However things work in ios, may be they use better technology,the client therefore not ready to encode the data in json.